# Java - Issue with "if" statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I must have some sort of syntax error somewhere, because both `correctip` and `loginip` are equal but my code is still saying they are not equal.

```
        if(correctip != loginip){
            event.disallow(null, "Access is denied to user " + name + ". If you believe this is in error, contact an admin.");
            System.out.println(loginip);
            System.out.println(correctip);
            System.out.println("[Denied] HIGHRISKUSER " + name + " denied login. IP Att: " + loginip + " | IP Cor: " + correctip);
        }else{
            System.out.println("[Allowed] HIGHRISKUSER " + name + " allowed login. IP Att: " + loginip + " | IP Cor: " + correctip);
        }
```

Both `correctip` and `loginip` are EXACTLY equal. Is there something else that could be causing problems?

Comment: Are they strings? If so you have to use .equals() function call

Comment: What type are `correctip` and `loginip`? If they're not ints or some other primitive you should use `loginip.equals(correctip)`

Comment: Refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1285418) for comparing String

Comment: They are strings, thanks I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`correctip` and `loginip` might be `String`. In that case, you should use the `equals` comparator:

```
if(correctip != null && correctip.equals(loginip)) {
    //your logic goes here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

if both variables are strings, you need to use `correctip.equals(loginip)` or `correctip.equalsIgnoreCase(loginip)` to compare them.

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of loginip and correctip?

Per your statement, I assume that the type should not be primitive(For example: int, long, short and so on). Instead, it would be a object (probably be string). so loginip or correctip is actually a reference of these two objects.

The equal-sign only assures the equality of its reference address. To compare two objects, you should use method `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `=`.